# Bash, Best logic for ending a function but not ending the script

Tags: bash, function

Function being called multiple times

```
_TestFun() {
local arg1=${1}
local arg2=${2}
local arg3=${3}
local arg4=${4}
local timearg1=${5}
local timearg2=${6}

testDATE=$(date |awk {' print $4 '}|cut -b 1-2)
 if [[ $testDATE == ${timearg1} ]] || [[ $testDATE == {timearg2} ]]; then
# exit ### I dont want to exit the script just this function if testDATE is true
 else
 continue
 fi

command1 ${arg4}" ${arg1}@${arg2} ${arg3}
}

_TestFun com1 com2 com3 com4 10 11
_TestFun com5 com6 com7 com8 20 21
```

I cant think what the answer might be.... :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `return` statement:

From `man bash`:

```
 If  the  builtin command return is executed in a function, the function
       completes and execution resumes with the next command after  the  func-
       tion  call.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `return` statement in _TestFun. And modify the script to have an exit after it has finished calling _TestFun

```
_TestFun com1 com2 com3 com4 10 11
_TestFun com5 com6 com7 com8 20 21
exit <status>;
```